# Origen de "lo mismo" como "quizá"

Tags: españa, adverbios, locuciones

La palabra *[mismo](https://dle.rae.es/mismo)* se usa para decir "idéntico", "exactamente igual", y para enfatizar lo dicho previamente en expresiones como "yo mismo", "hoy mismo", "aquí mismo", etc.

De esta palabra se derivan algunas expresiones idiomáticas, como "dar lo mismo", con el significado de "ser indiferente". Buscando en el CORDE, he visto que el origen de esta expresión viene sencillamente de frases como "en esta tienda me dan tal cosa por mi dinero, y en la otra tienda me dan lo mismo", de forma que ambas tiendas le dan lo mismo al comprador, al cual por tanto le resulta indiferente ir a una o a otra.

Sin embargo, la expresión que me intriga hoy es otra:

> **lo mismo**
>
> 1. loc. adv. **quizá**.

Dada la cantidad de coincidencias que hay en el CORDE de la expresión "lo mismo", me resulta difícil encontrar ejemplos que puedan aclarar el origen de "lo mismo" como "quizá", y en este caso no veo tan clara la relación entre ambos adverbios como en el caso del ejemplo anterior. ¿Cuál es el origen de esta asociación de significados entre "lo mismo" y "quizá"?

> *Lo mismo nos lo volvemos a encontrar y continuamos la fiesta.*
>
> Alfonso Grosso, "La zanja", 1961 (España).

Comment: Se me hace extraño ese significado. En Colombia oirías la la frase de la cita muy fácilmente como "Igual nos lo volveremos a encontrar y ..." pero en ese caso "lo mismo" e  "igual" significarían algo como "no importa", "como sea", "que más da" o "mmm" similar al uso en inglés de "whatever".

Comment: En Argentina también es extraño este uso. Coincide con lo que @DGaleano dice de Colombia. Nótese que "igual" también es diferente: en España significa "quizá", en Argentina para eso decimos "capaz (que)".

Comment: En España es un uso corriente. "- Pablo no ha vuelto. - Lo mismo se ha quedado en el bar".

Comment: En España «lo mismo» se puede sustiruir perfectamente siempre por «igual», es decir, no tiene un  significado diferente, es que coloquialmente, «igual»  tiene también el significado de «quizás». El origen de este uso lo desconozco, pero sospecho que viene de simplificar frases como «Igual podría  ganar o perder» o  «Igual gano o pierdo» que llevan implícita una probabilidad del 50% y de ahí a «igual gano» o «igual pierdo», donde ya se resalta una propabilidad  sobre la otra.

Comment: Me da la impresion que es una expresion poco usada