# Origen del uso de "de pronto" y "de repente" como "quizás"

Tags: etimología, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, colombia

Aprendí español hablando con alguien de Bogotá, Colombia. Cuando hablábamos, me daba cuenta de que muchas veces mi amiga empezaba sus frases con "de pronto" y nunca entendía porque no parecía que estaba hablando de cosas que estaban pasando "repentinamente".

La ultima vez que hablamos, me frustraba tanto que decidí preguntarle, solo para enterarme de que en su region de Colombia, se dice "de pronto" para referirse a la posibilidad, y se dice mas que las otras maneras más neutras de decirlo como "quizás" y "tal vez".

Luego, encontré algo en linea que en Venezuela, Perú y Uruguay, se hace lo mismo con "de repente".

Bueno, de esto viene la pregunta y por eso estoy aquí:

**¿De dónde viene el uso en ciertas regiones de "de pronto" y "de repente", que usualmente significan "repentinamente", para referirse a "quizás"?**

Comment: [Muy relacionada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/37172/12637), pero no duplicada.

Answer (score 2):

Tras una rápida búsqueda resulta ser que tanto “de repente” como “de pronto” se utilizan en muchos países americanos (en Argentina se escuchan bastante ambas formas, aunque yo personalmente no las uso casi nunca). No hay una explicación clara de su origen.

Una especulación que leí, y que yo había hecho por mi cuenta, considera que “de pronto” es una forma elíptica de **“de pronto se me ocurre la idea de que...”**, es decir, **“repentinamente se me aparece esta posibilidad en la mente”**, **“me viene a la mente esta idea, que quizás sea correcta”**, etc. Esta expresión elíptica se termina transformando en una simple muletilla o relleno, que se usa para insertar una pausa dubitativa. En casos donde el hablante quiere enfatizar que está diciendo algo dudoso o especulativo, yo he llegado a escuchar “quizás de pronto tal vez”, una tras otra, en ese orden, en conversaciones.

Los detalles gramaticales de la expresión varían según el lugar. Por lo que entiendo, en algunas regiones “de pronto” es equivalente a “posiblemente” y está lexicalizado de manera similar a “ojalá”, requiriendo o permitiendo una subordinada en subjuntivo. En Argentina no creo haber escuchado eso nunca, y “de pronto” es más bien, como dije arriba, más parecida a una muletilla o una interjección.